# How does giphy enable playback of animated gifs on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, gif, animated-gif, giphy

I'm fairly certain that I know how magnets work, but I am intrigued as to how http://giphy.com/ managed to get animated gif's to work on Facebook. Does anyone have a clue as to how this is done? Is it mime-type substitution or some undocumented type? All the other methods that I've researched do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently they get around it by converting it to flash. [Here's the Mashable article on it.](http://mashable.com/2013/08/29/facebook-does-not-support-gifs/) So technically they aren't gifs by the time they get to Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the gifs and not coverted to flash files. 
Facebook plays gif links by default. You just need to use the correct "og" tags for images while coding

```
<meta property="og:type" content="**video.other**" />
<meta property="og:title" content="***Your page title***" />
<meta property="og:url" content="***Your-image-url***" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="**image/gif**"
```

You should the following use facebook share debugger tool to compare and correct your coding.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

**Tip:** Paste a link from giphy and then your site to the facebook debugger tool and compare both of them while coding

Comment: The original post 3 years old now and as we all know FP allows gifs in this day and age :)